# Ubuntu Software Center search only returns magazines

Tags: software-center

No matter what I search for in Ubuntu Software Centre, the only search results are magazines. I'm searching from the top level category.

If I browse the categories manually (Graphics->3D for example), it shows no results. I can install and search for software in Synaptic without issues.

I've run `sudo apt-get update` from the terminal, it doesn't report any issues.

Is this likely to be a bug? I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

Screenshot: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbRna.png]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot ?

Comment: I've posted a link to a screenshot. It won't let me post an image in the post because I'm a new user...

Comment: Those are not magazines, those are thumbnails / pictures of the available applications. Try clicking on "Provided by Ubuntu".

Comment: I'm aware of what thumbnails are... I meant the results refer to e-magazines (such as EasyLinux Ausgabe).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question.

This sounds like the "app-install-data" package is not (correctly?) installed. Could you please install it via "sudo apt-get install --reinstall app-install-data

If that does not help, could you please open a terminal window (e.g. gnome-terminal) and run the command "software-center" there and paste the output messages it generates?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you click on "Show 101 technical items" at the bottom of the screenshot?

Or, your "Software Sources" entries could be incomplete.

Open the **Edit->Software Sources** menu (I'm on 11.10, YMMV), and make sure you have the categories you desire checked, select a reasonably local Ubuntu server, examine all the tabs and when you're done, click **Close** and exit Software Center. When next you run Software Center, it should pick up more than EasyLinux Ausgabe (which, I asume, in your example, had an article on "gimp") .